# JavaFX binding ComboBox values from table with different options per line with model

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

we want to create a combobox within a table. Each combobox should have different options based on the row. In our example we have a table with different server ip addresses and a combobox with all the users on that server.

We have no idea how to populate the different options to the combobox inside the CellFactory and also we are not sure how to bind the comboxbox entry with the corresponding model.

We created an example, maybe someone has ideas:

**CredentialModel**

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class CredentialModel {

    private StringProperty username = new SimpleStringProperty();

    private StringProperty password = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public CredentialModel(String username, String password) {
        setUsername(username);
        setPassword(password);
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username.get();
    }

    public StringProperty usernameProperty() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username.set(username);
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password.get();
    }

    public StringProperty passwordProperty() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password.set(password);
    }
}
```

**ServerModel**

```
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class ServerModel {

    private IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();


    private StringProperty ip = new SimpleStringProperty();

    private ObjectProperty<CredentialModel> credential = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    private ObservableList<CredentialModel> allCredentials = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ObservableList<CredentialModel> getAllCredentials() {
        return allCredentials;
    }

    public void setAllCredentials(ObservableList<CredentialModel> allCredentials) {
        this.allCredentials = allCredentials;
    }

    public ServerModel(Integer id, String ip) {
        setId(id);
        setIp(ip);
    }

    public String getIp() {
        return ip.get();
    }

    public StringProperty ipProperty() {
        return ip;
    }

    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip.set(ip);
    }

    public CredentialModel getCredential() {
        return credential.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<CredentialModel> credentialProperty() {
        return credential;
    }

    public void setCredential(CredentialModel credential) {
        this.credential.set(credential);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }

}
```

And the main application **TableApplication**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TableApplication extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        VBox box = new VBox();

        TableView<ServerModel> tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<ServerModel, String> ipColumn = new TableColumn<>("IP-Address");
        TableColumn<ServerModel, CredentialModel> userColumn = new TableColumn<>("Username");
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(ipColumn, userColumn);

        ipColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().ipProperty());

        tableView.getItems().addAll(populateTable());

        userColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<ServerModel,CredentialModel>, TableCell<ServerModel,CredentialModel>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<ServerModel, CredentialModel> call(TableColumn<ServerModel, CredentialModel> param) {
                return new UserComboBoxTableCell();
            }
        });

        Button button = new Button("Start");
        button.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getCredential().getUsername()));
        box.getChildren().addAll(tableView, button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(box,800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private ObservableList<ServerModel> populateTable() {

        ServerModel serverModel1 = new ServerModel(1, "192.168.0.1");
        serverModel1.setAllCredentials(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new CredentialModel("user1", "pw1"), new CredentialModel("user2", "pw2")));

        ServerModel serverModel2 = new ServerModel(2, "192.168.0.2");
        serverModel2.setAllCredentials(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new CredentialModel("user3", "pw3")));

        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(serverModel1, serverModel2);
    }
```

And the TableCellClass **UserComboBoxTableCell**

```
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;

public class UserComboBoxTableCell extends TableCell<ServerModel, CredentialModel> {

    public UserComboBoxTableCell() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(CredentialModel item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if(empty == false) {
            if(getTableRow() != null && getTableView() != null) {
                int index = getTableRow().getIndex();
                ServerModel serverModel = getTableView().getItems().get(index);

                ComboBox<CredentialModel> box = new ComboBox<>(serverModel.getAllCredentials());
                box.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(serverModel.credentialProperty());
                setGraphic(box);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea of the methode **loadCredentials** is that for each row this methode should be called for "dummy"-loading the credentials for the server row.

The idea of the **onAction** method of the button is to display the selected username from the selected serverrow. In the moment we just print the ip address because the credential is always null (because it is not binded in the moment).

Thanks for your help.
Hauke

**EDIT**
I just added an observable list of credential models to the server and populated the list view differently. But still I am not sure how to set the options to the combobox within the CellFactory because I need to access the row and I am not sure about the binding.

**EDIT2**
Now it is working. I updated the examples above.

Comment: sounds like your modeling is incomplete: ServerModel needs something like availableCredentialModels of which zero or 1 can be selected into credentialModel. Then update (bind) the combo's list based on those.

Comment: Thanks kleopatra - the idea of putting all available credentials to the server model is good and I modified the example above. But I have still the same problem how to put the options to the combobox and how to bind the data.

Comment: you need a custom tableCell that configures the combo in updateItem .. a side note: for list-valued properties, use ListProperty (not ObjectProperty<ObservableList>) - notification behavior is much better specified

Comment: Thanks kleopatra for bringing me on the right track - now it is working fine. I updated the question and the source code.

Comment: glad you found a solution :) Just a couple of comments: a) don't re-create the combo in every call of updateItem, instead do so once and re-configure with the list b) consider to re-use ComboBoxTableCell (though it has its quirks, could well be that going from scratch is the easier option ;) c) the serverModel is good enough for a simplified example - in your real code you certainly guard the credential property against setting values that are not contained :) And a meta issue: consider to post your solution as an answer (and accept it), such that it is easy for others to find it :)